# How can I find the Wolfenstein room?

Tags: rage, wolfenstein-3d

In RAGE, I have heard that there is a secret level as a homage to id Software's game Wolfenstein 3D.

Where can I find this level and what do I need to do in order to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the secret Wolfenstein room, you will need to do the following;

- After the introduction to your defibrilator, exit the room you wake up in
- Follow the level around until you reach the outside section of the level, you will need to kill multiple enemies
- Once outside, instead of following the level off to the left, turn right and head into the dead end that has the TV set in it
- Next to the TV set a section of wall looks a bit off colour with a blue glow coming from under the wall
- "Use" the wall to access the secret Wolfenstein room

Here is a youtube video detailing how to find this hidden room: